# Could it be ubuntu installed alondside windows 10 on the same disk C?

Tags: grub2, windows-10, 22.04, usb-installation, rufus

I have a brand new laptop with preinstalled windows 10 but only disk C (500Gb), I wanna install ubuntu alongside windows and remain 200GB to win and 300 to ubuntu.

Can I install it to the same partition? Or do I need to create another partition? Is it better to make repartition from windows or better don't touch it to prevent paging/fragmenting and create a new partition from ubuntu installation process?

Comment: No, you cannot install Ubuntu to the same partition unless you want to install Ubuntu in a VM running on top of Windows. For installation instructions, please refer to the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop).  On [Page 6](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-drive-management) there is a link to complete instructions for setting up dual boot configuration with an existing Windows installation.  You will need to shrink your Windows partition so that there is enough unallocated free space for Ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) -- I suggest you follow the tutorial in my first comment, but this question also has a wealth of information. If you encounter issues, please start a new question. Be sure to reference the tutorial and provide context and details if you need further assistance

Comment: I just follow the installation instruction, it split the disk equally (~250Gb each) I'm not fully satisfied but nevertheless it's quite well done for me, but thank you anyway

Comment: You can choose how to split the disk, or can resize later.